# Rails query timestamp delta from GMT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Time stamps are saved, via postgresql, as:  `"1991-12-02 01:11:00.000000000 +0100"`.

However, there are a number of records that were created with elements of data that are off and the console returns timezone adjusments as

```
 LMT +00:49
```

*There is no clue why an offset ended up being `+00:49`...*

How can these records be queried and subsequently adjusted so that the time is the existing value + 1 hour AND showing the timezone as CET +0100 ?

The attribute is of datatype `datetime`, whereas LMT is GMT `+ 0100`

Comment: What is the data type (timestamp without time zone  or timestamp with time zone). BTW Postgres does not store timestamps in any year:month:day... format; they are stored in an internal structure. Further the UTC offset/Timezone is **not** stored, it is retrieved from the server.  LMT is GMT?

Comment: Postgres does not have a data type *datetime* must be a Rails datatype. Sign-in directly to your database from a console and enter command `\d+ tablename`. It will show the complete table description. Post that description, as text - **not an image**.

Comment: @Belayer The rails schema type `datetime` corresponds to `timestamp` in Postgres. The OP here is falling for the age old trap of thinking that a timestamp and its original timezone can be stored in a single column.

Comment: PostgreSQL (with the default config) does not know a timezone abbreviated 'LMT'.  Either you have a weird compilation/configuration of PostgreSQL. or this is something Ruby is foisting onto you.

Comment: @Belayer. the postgresql datatype is  `timestamp without time zone`

Comment: @jjanes. correct, there are a number of records that have an offset of ` +0049` which ought to be `+0100` Something has occured at the ruby or rails level on those records and the goal is to effect this change.

Comment: Rome had an offset of 49 minutes for part of its history, but that ended 130 years ago.  I don't know what else it could be.  Are you using the Rome timezone?

Comment: Could LMT be [Local mean time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually store a timestamp and its original timezone in a single column.*

This is a pretty common source of confusion but Postgres (and many other databases) actually store dates/time as an internal number-y type. In previous versions the default varied between a double precision float or a 8-bit integer (it's not stated in the current version of the docs).

Neither `time`, `date`, `timestamp` or `timestamp with zone` (despite the confusion caused by the name) store any information about the original timezone - it merely changes how the input is coerced into the database timezone or UTC.

To be able to implement this feature you'll need to store the original timezone in a separate column and then convert the stored time into the original timezone. Depending on your needs this can either be [done in Rails](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) or in Postgres with [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT).

See:

- [It's About Time (Zones)](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones)
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: * Of course its possible to use a something like a text column or that someone has written a Postgres extension with a custom type that does this.